# Write to STDIN programmatically for Select()

Tags: stdin

I placed select() in a loop waiting for inputs in commandline. Is there anyway to write to STDIN programmatically and then let select() capture it?

I have tried write(), fputs() to STDIN but select() still cannot see the change in STDIN.

```
while( 1 ){
    ....
    rt = select(fdmax+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &time_out);

    if ( rt == 0 ) // if it timesout, write to STDIN for the next loop
    {
       char message[20] = "hihihihi\n";
       write(STDIN, message, strlen(message));

       printf("wrote\n");
       continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Construct a command by putting a string into a tty](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48103/construct-a-command-by-putting-a-string-into-a-tty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends very much on the nature of the file open on stdin.

If it was a regular file, `select` would always return with something to read.

If it's a pipe or socket, you need to write data at the other end of that socket. If you don't have a file descriptor open to the other end, on Linux, you can get one by opening `/proc/self/fd/0` in write mode.

If it's a terminal device, you can use the `TIOCSTI` ioctl.

You can use `fstat` to determine the type of file and in the case of a character device, use `isatty` to check if the device is a terminal device.

Comment: Thanks. It was a terminal device. TIOSCTI worked. So where does write() write to if the fd is STDIN?

Comment: If fd 0 has been open in read+write mode on a terminal device, then `write(0,"data")` will write data to that device, and writing to a terminal device causes that data to be sent to the other end (in the case of a pty to the terminal emulator for display or to sshd to send to the ssh client...), while reading from the device reads the data sent by the other end. If it has been open in read-only mode, then the write will return with a EBADF error.